# BigQuery Create Table from CSV - Create Columns automatically

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table from a large CSV with 300 columns.

In the create table ui it is asking me to type up what each column should be called and its data type. Is there a way to automatically have each delimited field as a column and have the first row as the column name instead of having to manually type this in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use schema auto-detect (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources#auto-detect) but this is not currently supported from the UI so you'll have to do it from the CLI.